# Cannot get value in JS object and overwriting the key adds a duplicate

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

The object **data** is from a .NET backend API. I log the output in JS.

```
24 console.log(data["Approved Variations"]);
25 data["Approved Variations"] = "Approved Elephants";
26 console.log(data["Approved Variations"]);
27 console.log(data);
```

The first key's value is undefined. I add it, but the expected key exists when inspecting the data.

```
ProjectLocalization.js:24 undefined
ProjectLocalization.js:26 Approved Elephants
ProjectLocalization.js:27 {
Approved Variations: "Approved Elephants"
Variations: "Variations"
Approved Variations: "Approved Cats"
}
```

Why can I not get the key's value, and why are there now duplicate keys? Does this suggest the key name is somehow encoded differently? It only appears to happen for keys with a space in the name.

**UPDATE**

When I console.log the array of keys, I get the below, which to the naked eye appears identical.

[image]

But the below is returning false, suggesting they are not equivalent?

```
    console.log(keyArray[25] === keyArray[27]);
```

Interested to understand what can cause that.

Comment: It seems impossible. Are you sure the key `Approved Variations` with value `Approved Cats` is the same as the other one? No hidden/similar/white space characters by mistake?

Comment: Assign both values to string variables. Check both strings have equal lengths. Then use the `charCodeAt()` method to get the code of each character and compare. There could be a diacritic mark somewhere, or a space-like character that is not U+0020.

Comment: Thanks both. @OldGeezer thanks for pointing me in that direction, the first one is char code 32 and the second one is char code 160 - one is a space and the other is a no-break space apparently!